# How to display the specific image when clicked from a grid view

Tags: android

I am displaying some images in my application using a grid view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

this is the following code which handles the images

```
public class Gallery extends Activity {
    Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d,
            R.drawable.e,
            R.drawable.f,
            R.drawable.g,
            R.drawable.k,
            R.drawable.j,
            R.drawable.i,
            R.drawable.h,

    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
            View v, int position, long id) 
            {                
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            context = c;
        }

        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item--- 
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
    }    
}
```

I would like to display the specific image in full size when it is clicked from the screen.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Where do you want to display the image? In a new Activity or in this one?

Comment: I want to display in new activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to display your Image in a new Activity, I would do something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {                
    Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this, DisplayActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Image Int", imageIDs[position]);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your displaying Activity use:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);

    int imageInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("Image Int", R.drawable.oops); // oops should be a fallback if an error happens
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageInt);
}
```

Comment: If you are having trouble, you need to be specific... Have you created a layout named `display.xml` that has an ImageView with the id `@+id/imageView`? Are you getting any errors? If so post the LogCat in your question, then let me know that you have done this.

Comment: yah I did that I am passing the imageid as long and according to the value of that I am assigning an image from drawable....and in my xml I have included just one imageview no layout and there is one warning saying 'missing content description attribute on image, Is there any problem

Comment: ah resolved the problem, It was an issue with my calling function

Comment: can u tell me how to achieve highlighting specific image of my choice instead of default imageview while switching between activities.

Answer (score 4):

In your OnItemClickListener you should add that you want to start a new activity and pass it the position of the image by putExtra:

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this,FullImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("imgPos",position);
            Gallery.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

As you see in the intent you call a FullImage class, which you should create:

```
    public class FullImage extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
    int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("imgPos");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(Gallery.imageIDs[position]);

}
```

}

And this is what the full_image layout could look like, note that it has an ImageView with id full_image_view that was revered to in the FullImage class

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" > 
<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

You should make your ImageIDs a static Integer so that it can be referenced in the FullImage class.

Finally, don't forget to add the FullImage activity in the AndroidManifest.

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on position get image from imageIds and display it - start new activity and pass image id or how you wish.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                
            int imageId = imageIDs[position];
            //now you have clicked imageId so display it where you want
        }
    });
```