# Android grid layout auto adjust

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I need to have a grid layout, with uniform tiles, on click on one tile, it should expand and reorder the remaining tiles in the view. How can I achieve that.

Here is the image representation of what I need.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using GridView, and check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276207/how-to-display-the-specific-image-when-clicked-from-a-grid-view

Comment: Why there is down vote?